# How to remove the + characters of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove the character + from the following string:

```
let myString = 'Ryu+Ken+Chun-Li+Cammy+Guile+Sakura+Sagat+Juri';

I have tried to do but nothing changes:
let myArray = ['Ryu+Ken+Chun-Li+Cammy+Guile+Sakura+Sagat+Juri'];

var removeItem = "+";

 myArray = myArray.filter(function(item) {
 return item !== removeItem;
})

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: If you need an array instead of @Quentin suggest you can use [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Are you trying to remove or replace `+` with `space`? In that case try this way`myString .replaceAll('+', ' ')`

Answer (score -1):

```js
let myString = 'Ryu+Ken+Chun-Li+Cammy+Guile+Sakura+Sagat+Juri';
let myArray = myString.split('+')

console.log(myArray);
```